# The transitivity of strict generalized inequality

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I am reading Section 2.4.1 in Boyd's Convex Optimization, where the proper cone and the generalized inequality are defined. Specifically, given proper cone $\mathcal{K}\subset \mathcal{R}^n$ and $x$, $y\in\mathcal{R}^{n}$, $x\preceq_{\mathcal{K}}y\Leftrightarrow y-x\in\mathcal{K}$.

Transitivity is not included in the list of properties of **strict** generalized inequality (Page 44).

May I ask why strict generalized inequality is not transitive? Could you please introduce a counterexample to me?

Comment: Strict inequality in ordered Banach spaces is transitive: The interior ${\rm Int} K$ of a solid cone $K$ is convex. If $y-x, z-y \in {\rm Int} K$, then $\frac{1}{2}((z-y)+(y-x)) \in {\rm Int K}$ and therefore $z-x = 2(\frac{1}{2}(z-x)) \in {\rm Int} K$.

Comment: Hi Gerd. Thank you for your kind comment. I have the same conclusion as you. So, strict generalized inequality is transitive, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. I think the point is that the interior of a cone is a cone itself (it is convex and invariant under multiplication with scalars $> 0$).

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. @Gerd